# Merging data:application/octet-stream;base64 video chunks into a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, base64, fs

I have an upload button on my page which user can click to upload a video. If video is large, Javascript's File Reader can't handle it. So I've implemented a function that slices uploaded video into chunks with 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' label at the beginning. Meanwhile the function sends each chunk to the NodeJS backend, where I use some 'fs' approaches to merge the video file back and save it as an mp4 file on my disc. The problem is that the file is 'empty'. It's recognized by my PC as an mp4 file, there is no error of wrong file format. But the video has no content and it's 0 seconds long. How can I merge chunks properly to make the mp4 file work?

Frontend:

```
let reader;
let file;
const slice_size = 1024;

const start_chunks_upload = (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    reader = new FileReader();
    file = e.target.files[0];
    
    upload_file_chunks(0);
}

const upload_file_chunks = (start) => {
    const next_slice = start + slice_size + 1;
    const blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);

    reader.onloadend = (e) => {

        if (e.target.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/video',
            data: {
                video: e.target.result.replace('data:application/octet-stream;base64,', ''),
                is_done: next_slice < file.size ? null : true,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                const size_done = start + slice_size;
                const percent_done = Math.floor((size_done / file.size) * 100);

                console.log(percent_done + '%');

                if (next_slice < file.size) {
                    upload_file_chunks(next_slice);
                } else {
                    console.log('done');
                }
            }
        });
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

video_upload_button.addEventListener('change', (e) => start_chunks_upload(e));
```

Backend:

```
let string = '';

app.post('/video', (req, res) => {

    string += req.body.video;

    if (req.body.is_done) {

        let buff = new Buffer.from(string, 'base64');

        fs.writeFileSync('/one.mp4', buff);
        
        fs.writeFile("/two.mp4", string, 'base64', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        fs.appendFile('/log.txt', string, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
        })
    } else {      
        return res.json({ok: 1,});
    }
})
```

Comment: Use a **hex editor** to check the differences between bytes of original file versus your re-saved file. It seems your code is just slicing and then re-saving the exact same chunks, right? So the newly saved file should be a duplicate of the input original, right?

Comment: Let me know what you see in the hex editor (matching or different bytes?, and if different then explain in what way there is a difference?).

Comment: I have decided to try another solution. I've used formdata to post whole file to my backend with readAsArrayBuffer method in my FileReader.